# Actionscript and JS - DOM events

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, actionscript

I wondered if anyone can provide any information on how flash events relate to the DOM event model.

My issue is this:

body > div > object

The div has a mousedown event which calls 'preventDefault' on the event object.

This shouldn't bear any relation to a click event within the objects swf however in IE9 it prevents the swfs mousedown event from firing...

I'm struggling to understand how swf events fit in with DOM (presumably they continue to bubble up from the object element?) and why a click event on a div would affect a childs swf click.

Can anyone help explain?

Rich

Comment: Just for clarification, are you asking to compare the event flow in ActionScript to the event flow in JavaScript, or are you asking what the complete event flow is with both JavaScript *and* ActionScript?

Comment: I'm interested in the complete event flow with both JavaScript and ActionScript. I'm trying to work out why, in IE9, preventing the default action on mouse down of an objects parent div stops an ActionScript mousedown event from firing - 

I'm hoping that getting a better understanding of the relationship between JS and AS events will help me work out what's going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an event-order dump from a simple flash file that logs it's events to the DOM console via ExternalInterface, additionally I've bound click events to the `body`, `div`, and `object` elements via jQuery (the `object` element does not seem to fire mouse events in the DOM).

```
mouseDown [object MovieClip] [object Stage] c
mouseDown [object MovieClip] [object DocumentClass] c
mouseDown [object MovieClip] [object MovieClip] c
mouseDown [object MovieClip] [object MovieClip]
mouseDown [object MovieClip] [object DocumentClass]
mouseDown [object MovieClip] [object Stage]
mousedown [object HTMLObjectElement] [object HTMLDivElement]
mousedown [object HTMLObjectElement] [object HTMLBodyElement]
mouseUp [object MovieClip] [object Stage] c
mouseUp [object MovieClip] [object DocumentClass] c
mouseUp [object MovieClip] [object MovieClip] c
mouseUp [object MovieClip] [object MovieClip]
mouseUp [object MovieClip] [object DocumentClass]
mouseUp [object MovieClip] [object Stage]
click [object MovieClip] [object Stage] c
click [object MovieClip] [object DocumentClass] c
click [object MovieClip] [object MovieClip] c
click [object MovieClip] [object MovieClip]
click [object MovieClip] [object DocumentClass]
click [object MovieClip] [object Stage]
mouseup [object HTMLObjectElement] [object HTMLDivElement]
mouseup [object HTMLObjectElement] [object HTMLBodyElement]
click [object HTMLObjectElement] [object HTMLDivElement]
click [object HTMLObjectElement] [object HTMLBodyElement]
```

You'll notice that I've also added listeners for the capturing phase in ActionScript. I didn't bother for JS, as jQuery doesn't seem to have a simplified way of handling capturing phase events.

This particular dump was performed in Firefox 4, so there may be inconsistencies across browsers with whether DOM events fire before ActionScript events.

Given the bubbling event model, this particular behavior makes sense, although it is important to note that the ActionScript `MOUSE_UP` and `CLICK` events fire before the DOM's `mouseup` and `click` events.

I'm going to hazard a guess that IE9 is allowing the bubbling/capturing phase events to execute before calling any ActionScript events.